# Improve tag wiki for "symbol" to mention that titles have to describe the symbol

Tags: discussion, tagwiki

The [symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbol) seems to suffer from bad titles quite often. This might only be subjective, but I have the feeling that there are often questions like

> How to I make this symbol?

where they really write "this symbol" and to not describe the symbol. (I've just corrected this problem for [What is this symbol consisting of a horizontal line crossed by a rotated vertial line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/206840/5645).)

The problem of those titles is that it makes it hard for others who have the same question to find the question.

I think we should mention that in the tag wiki. But I don't know how to formulate it. Could somebody please have a look at it?

Comment: The first action a Q like this will most likely get is a link to [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14) and meybe even closed as duplicate (if the symbol is widely used and contained with some package).

Comment: I think vagueness of the titles are justified in this particular case. You wouldn't name it as *how can I draw a slanted goat head without a face* to ask for `\gamma` for the sake of nonvagueness

Comment: @percusse On the other hand, you can say: _How can I reproduce this letter-like symbol?_ or _Looking for a symbol: square with a squirrel inside_ or such.

Comment: We _cannot_ put links into teh excerpts, right? :-/

Comment: @tohecz Why do you want to put a link in the excerpt?

Comment: @moose I thought of either linking the universal symbols question there, or making a "how to ask how to get a symbol" FAQ here on meta and linking this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear describing the symbol in the title is always an improvement or helps later searches, in fact sometimes rather the opposite.

Some special symbols need special answers but most likely these questions get answered by some general advice on how to look up a symbol, or get closed as duplicates of "How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?" in which case presumably any advice given is helpful to anyone looking up any symbol and so making it look like a specific question about say "a pile of poo" (Unicode U+F4A9) would just make it more likely that people looking for other symbols don't find the advice.

Comment: Ok. You should eventually link to the question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5645

Comment: but what about (non-alphabetic) symbols that (1) aren't in unicode, but (2) have published instances that can be cited, and (3) those published instances have a well-defined (if possibly not currently in vogue) meaning?